# What are the parameters for Kanai's Cube when upgrading rare items?

Tags: diablo-iii

The Kanai's Cube has a power to:

Upgrade Rare Item: Upgrades the quality of a level 70 Rare item to Legendary. This item will roll as a randomized Legendary that shares that item's equipment type.

Does legendary in this case also include a chance to be a green set item of that equipment type?

Is this upgrade only going to upgrade for the class in which you are currently playing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can now attest first hand that set items are possible, got a [Uliana's Strength](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/ulianas-strength) upgrading a rare shoulder piece with my monk.

With these 2 [reddit's](https://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/3ikfhm/kanais_cube_transformation_upgrade_rare_to/) [threads](https://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/3cfct0/kanai_cube_upgrade_rare_item_question/) confirming this also, I'm confident enough to say that the items upgraded will all be for the class they are being upgraded with. Else, set items would not be 100% sure of being for the class upgrading the items which would seem strange.

That is also consistent with crafted items that have stats for the class crafting them.

But, the class-only items will roll with their class stats. I tested with a voodoo mask and got [image]

Comment: I have also received ancient set items and ancient legendaries through the cube this way. Basically you do a tweaked smart loot roll, "tweaked" meaning that you pick a random item of the same type but the rest appears to be smart loot in effect.