# Which rare belt do I need to upgrade to get a Sebor's Nightmare?

Tags: diablo-iii

Using Kanai's Cube, I can upgrade a rare item to a legendary using the correct recipe.  If I want to end up with Sebor's Nightmare, do I have to start with a particular type of belt?  If so, which type - they all just say "belt"?

In general, how would I know which rare item would be needed to upgrade to a chosen legendary item?

Comment: Related [question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/233568/what-are-the-parameters-for-kanais-cube-when-upgrading-rare-items)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't upgrade rare items to a specific legendary item. What you get by upgrading is a random legendary of the same type, e.g if you upgrade a rare belt, you get a legendary belt; if you upgrade a rare helm, you get a legendary helm; if you upgrade a rare spirit stone, you get a legendary spirit stone, etc.

Comment: So any "rare belt" will do, and it could turn into any of the legendary belts? And are "mighty belts" a fundamentally different type in this context?

Comment: Yes, mighty belts are different to normal belts, you can also get set items from upgrading.

Comment: All rare items are the same at level 70 anyways, they just have randomized names, there aren't different "types" as suggested by OP.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill There are different appearances of items, and didn't know if that made a difference.